# How to implement loading display with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loading

I am returning data from a php file using ajax. But it would look good if a loading display came up, like an animated gif or something. I have had a go using text but noting shows up. Is there a better way of doing it than I have.

```
function small_loader(t){
    if(t === 'show'){
        $('#sub_menu').html('Loading');
    }else{
        $('#sub_menu').html('');
    }
}
function loadtools(t){
    var tools = 'tools/'+t+'.php';
    $.ajax({
        url:tools,
        type:'POST',
        beforeSend: function(){
            small_loader('show');
        },
        success: function(e){
            $('#sub_menu').html(e);
        },
        complete:function(){
            small_loader('hide');
        }
    });
}
```

At the moment the php file just has a for loop on it echoing out numbers with kine breaks for testing purposes. This does work if I take the small_loader function off. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You set #sub_menu to 'Loading...' then put the AJAX stuff there, then at the end overwrite it with '' when you disable the loader, overwriting the ajax response.

Try using a different div for the loader, and maybe hide the #sub_menu and display it when it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your loader in your HTML (at the right place, say beside the button launching the ajax request), hide it in css (display:none), show it before sending your request and hide it when response comes back :

```
function loadtools(t){
    var tools = 'tools/'+t+'.php';
    $.ajax({
        url:tools,
        type:'POST',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#your_loader_wrapper_id").show();
        },
        success : ...,
        error : ...,
        complete: function(e){
            $("#your_loader_wrapper_id").hide();
            $('#sub_menu').html(e);
        }
    });
}
```